# Плавный скролл в google chrome

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:

```js
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, {passive: false} );
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
  else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

  handle(delta);
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
}

var goUp = true;
var end = null;
var interval = null;

function handle(delta) {
  var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
  var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

  if (end == null) {
    end = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
  end -= 20 * delta;
  goUp = delta > 0;

  if (interval == null) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
      if (scrollTop <= 0 || 
          scrollTop >= $(window).prop("scrollHeight") - $(window).height() ||
          goUp && step > -1 || 
          !goUp && step < 1 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        end = null;
      }
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop + step );
    }, animationInterval);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  
  <main>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem repellat, fugiat iusto nam debitis magnam temporibus! Eius harum commodi ut suscipit veritatis accusantium ex at, vitae. Possimus deserunt totam perferendis veniam maiores nihil! Doloremque aliquam voluptate aperiam, eos nulla dolor?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique molestiae cupiditate obcaecati consectetur dolor facilis quod consequuntur est cumque pariatur sed sint neque hic magni aliquid, cum placeat blanditiis! Ab cupiditate harum placeat, esse quaerat neque! Nam est excepturi, ab accusamus provident error, beatae mollitia rem deserunt architecto earum quos. Magnam animi harum perspiciatis autem id vitae doloremque, ducimus est fugit illum aspernatur tempora temporibus at esse voluptate possimus deserunt nesciunt corrupti mollitia odit, veniam architecto. Ea, consequatur, enim. Facilis ipsam numquam cum earum molestias, ab sequi reiciendis distinctio necessitatibus illum! Laborum error autem repudiandae rerum cum, dicta voluptatibus! Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae dolore eum molestias possimus dolor voluptatibus aliquid nobis quia dolorum nulla!
    </p>
  </main>
```

Плавность скролла, везде работает и работало в хроме до недавнего времени.

Теперь начала вылазить ошибка:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive. See

И плавный скролл в хроме не работает.

**Вопрос:** Что за ошибка и как решить проблему плавного скролла в google chrome для данного кода?

Comment: проблема в строке `window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;` - как можно заметить, тут passive Не задается, следовательно он `true`, следовательно внутри запрещен `preventDefault`

Comment: У вас подключен jquery, почему бы им не пользоваться в полной мере?

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте

```
{ capture: false, passive: false }
```

вместо

```
{ passive: false }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забывайте вместе с кодом оставлять краткое пояснение к нему.